# Monitor's auto adjustment feature doesn't work

Tags: display, lcd, desktop-computer

When I click the auto adjustment button on my Samsung desktop LCD monitor, my screen changes its appearance, my desktop moves downwards, half of the taskbar is hidden and a small blank bar appears on the top. I'm running Windows 7.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to use a digital connection like DVI instead - then you don't need auto adjustment anymore.

Anyway if you prefer to stick with the "good old VGA signal" you should make sure that the image shown on the monitor when pressing auto adjustment button should not contain large spaces of a solid color. An image where each pixel as a different color compared to the one surrounding is best (especially to those left and right).

Furthermore I assume that your monitor can be also adjusted manually if the auto adjustment does not work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In the Windows 7 "Screen Resolution" dialog, try setting the resolution to the maximum resolution recommended for your monitor.  Then try the auto-adjust again.

My assumption is you're using VGA to connect which only sends RGB info (to my knowledge).  When you auto-adjust, the monitor is trying to optimize the color values for the display and make sure the resolution specified by Windows 7 will fit on the monitor.  If you have less than maximum resolution, it will probably try to stretch the pixels and move the image around.

I agree with the previous post... just use DVI.

Answer (score 0):

I went in to the device manager and found that the monitor was listed under ports as unknown device but not under monitors. I right clicked on the device and clicked on update driver and selected automatically update. Then the monitor was listed under monitors as pnp monitor. This solved the issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just Chose a Low profile wallpaper.

As an example: if your screen resolution is 1400x900, use a wallpaper resolution of 800x600, 
then press *auto adjustment*.